# Not able to access env variables in kubernetes pod

Tags: bash, kubernetes

In my pod I have some env variables. I have written a bash script to get inside the pod and connect to database using the env variables. But am not able to use the env variables.

```sh
kubectl exec $POD_ID  -- /bin/bash -c """
     printenv DATABASE_HOST_NAME
     echo $DATABASE_HOST_NAME
     psql -h $DATABASE_HOST_NAME -U DATABASE_USER
"""
```

Here printenv returns the correct env variable value. echo returns empty. And psql statement doesn't take the host.
Anyone has any idea how i can use the env variables in the pod in my psql connection statement.

When i manually get in the container and run the psql command with env variable it works file.But when running the script it shows the error.

Comment: its defined inside pod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `DATABASE_HOST_NAME` is defined in k8s pod, you need single quote to avoid `$DATABASE_HOST_NAME` to be expanded on the host.

```
kubectl exec $POD_ID  -- /bin/bash -c '
     printenv DATABASE_HOST_NAME
     echo $DATABASE_HOST_NAME
     psql -h $DATABASE_HOST_NAME -U DATABASE_USER
'
```